# How to remove dash inside text with CSS?

Tags: css, text

In a page, I've got some text generated automatically like this:

Edward-Hopper-Grand-Palais

What I want is to remove the dash to remplace it by whitespace or a space with CSS.
Is that possible?

Thank for helping

Comment: You have to use DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with CSS, but with Javascript you can do this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function parseDisplay( result )
    {
        var displayedText = true;

        for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++)
        {
            var c = result.charAt(x);

            if (c == '<')
            {
                displayedText = false;  
            }
            else if (c == '>')
            {
                displayedText = true;   
            }

            if (displayedText && c == '-')
            {   
                result = result.substring(0,x) + ' ' + result.substring(x + 1, result.length);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
</script>
```

If you are using this results for ID's or classes this function will leave everything inside of '< >' tags completely untouched! When you generate it just run it through this function before you display it!

Comment: Why complicate things so much?

Comment: I needed to use this function to replace dashes with spaces on displayed html, but I didnt want it to change the ID's and Classes of my divs, so I pass all of my AJAX results through this. It really is just a String replace function that has an added feature. It's a pretty simple function. The displayedText variable keeps track of whether that portion of the string will be seen by the user, and if it is seen by the user and contains an underscore, I replace it with a space by grabbing the string before that point, a space, and a string after that point.

Comment: I see, but what if we already are aware of the specific "id" or "class" that produces the hyphenated text, then we can achieve what we want with just 3 lines of code. But I think you are considering the case where we aren't.

Comment: Yeah, the text I need to pass through is product information generated in bulk, and I use the Product Numbers and categories from the database to define my classes so I need to use hyphenated text, but when I display the information I want it to show up without the hyphenated product names and categories.

Comment: Your answer is probably closer to what he was looking for though! Its a solid answer :)

Answer (score 3):

### http://jsfiddle.net/WYGu3/

Suppose you've a piece of markup such as this:

```
<p id="text"> Edward-Hopper-Grand-Palais </p>
```

Then the fastest way to perform a replace would be:

```
var str = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
str = str.replace(/-/g, ' ');
alert(str);
```

The `/g` here performs a global replace.

Comment: Thank you Ali, but in my case, it doesn't work.  I guess it's because my text is generated by a variable:  <span id="sstiret">{$product.category}</span> so that's why I was looking for a CSS solution...

Comment: Why don't you share your complete code and how the text is being generated so we don't have to speculate the exactness of the situation. I think you can use DOM to manipulate the HTML inside "sstiret". Share your full code and the work flow that accompanies it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do such things with CSS. The hyphen characters do not constitute elements, so they cannot be referred to in CSS.

Very theoretically, you could create a font that has a space in place of hyphen and use that font via `@font-face`. But that would be awkward, and the hyphens would just *look* like spaces (e.g., copying content and pasting it as plain text would give you hyphens, not spaces).

So you need to modify the content server-side or client-side, as suggested in other answers.